# How can you prevent both jumpiness, and interrupting tweens with animated Flash buttons?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

This is something I've never been able to figure out.

You've got a button offscreen you want to animate in. We'll call it 'btn.'
You've got a hit area that serves as the proximity sensor to trigger btn's animation. We'll call it 'hitZone' (as to not cause confusion with the hitArea property of display objects).

[image: btn is off stage and hitZone is the white box with the blue border]

Both btn and hitZone are MovieClips. The listeners go something like this.

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
var endPoint:Number = 31;

hitZone.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onHitZoneOver);
hitZone.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onHitZoneOut);
hitZone.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onHitZoneClick);

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onBtnOver);
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onBtnOut);
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBtnClick);
btn.mouseChildren = false;

function onHitZoneOver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    TweenLite.to(btn, 0.75, {x:endPoint, ease:Expo.easeOut});
    trace("over hitZone");
}

function onHitZoneOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    TweenLite.to(btn, 0.75, {x:-1, ease:Expo.easeOut});
    trace("out hitZone");
}

function onBtnOver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    hitZone.mouseEnabled = false;
    hitZone.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onHitZoneOver);
    hitZone.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onHitZoneOut);
    trace("over BTN");

    // This line is the only thing keeping the btn animation from being fired continuously
    // causing jumpiness. However, calling this allows the animation to be interrupted 
    // at any point.
    TweenLite.killTweensOf(btn);
}

function onBtnOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    hitZone.mouseEnabled = true;
    hitZone.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onHitZoneOver);
    hitZone.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onHitZoneOut);
    trace("out BTN");
}

function onBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("click BTN");
}

function onHitZoneClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
        trace("click hitZone");
}
```

The issue is when your mouse is over both the hitZone *and* btn. The button continuously jumps unless you call TweenLite.killAllTweensOf(). This fixes the jumpiness, but it introduces a new problem. Now, it's very easy to interrupt the animation of the btn at any point, stopping it before it's totally visible on the stage.

I've seen [similar](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=350932) posts, but even they suffer from the same issue. Perhaps it's a problem with how Flash detects edges, because I've never once seen a workaround for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC to fix this issue, when dealing with proximity zones, I used the mouse position to show/hide the content (the button). I would use the hitZone to trigger a mouse move listener. Once the mouse position is outside the hitZone: hide the button and remove the mouse move listener.

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
var endPoint:Number = 31;

hitZone.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onHitZoneOver);
hitZone.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onHitZoneClick);

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onBtnOver);
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onBtnOut);
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBtnClick);
btn.mouseChildren = false;

function onHitZoneOver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    TweenLite.to(btn, 0.75, {x:endPoint, ease:Expo.easeOut});
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMoved);
    hitZone.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onHitZoneOver);
    trace("over hitZone");
}

function onHitZoneOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    TweenLite.to(btn, 0.75, {x:-1, ease:Expo.easeOut});
    trace("out hitZone");
}

function onBtnOver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("over BTN");
}

function onBtnOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("out BTN");
}

function onBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("click BTN");
}

function onHitZoneClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
        trace("click hitZone");
}

function onMouseMoved(e:MouseEvent):void
{
        if( !hitZone.hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY) )
        {
            trace("Sacrebleu!");
            TweenLite.to(btn, 0.75, {x:-41, ease:Expo.easeOut});
            stage.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMoved );
            hitZone.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onHitZoneOver);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if I got it right, but perhaps you should remove the onHitZoneOver listener right away and wait until the button tween is complete so you can trigger it again;

Something like this:

`hitZone.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hitAreaOver);

hitZone.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, hitAreaOut);`

function onHitZoneOver(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    hitZone.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hitAreaOver);
    TweenLite.to(btn, 0.75, {x:endPoint, ease:Expo.easeOut});
    trace("over hitZone");
}

function onHitZoneOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    TweenLite.to(btn, 0.75, {x:-1, ease:Expo.easeOut});
    trace("out hitZone");
    hitZone.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hitAreaOver);
}